# dataTaskWithRequest crashes with 302 redirect response - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, api

I am trying to get the response information for a request I am making, which gives back a 302 response. (I was able to use an online API request caller and get it back). However, when I try to do it within my application, it crashes. My code right now is:

```
func openVideo() {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://uapi-f1.picovico.com/v2.1/v/nMirP/ArwenUndomiel.mp4")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        print(response)
    })

    task!.resume()

}
```

I have tried to use Alamofire to do this, but the code has not been updated for Swift 2.0 and therefore, I would like to stick to Swift if possible.

Answer (score -2):

```
task!.resume()
```

should be

```
task.resume()
```

because dataTaskWithRequest will not return an optional value, so you dont need to unwrap it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:

Comment: It will tell me to insert the exclamation point if I take it out.

Comment: I think this might be a bug in Xcode. What version are you running?

Also, try a clean + restart xcode

Comment: I am running XCode 7.2 and I have been using the "task!.resume()" syntax throughout the rest of my code. Unfortunately, after clean and restarting, it does not work.

Comment: What line is it crashing on?

Comment: It doesn't point to a line but gives me a "com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader (8): EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)"